# How to find the lower limit of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$a_n =\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{4n-5}$$

I dont understand why the lower limit isnt equal to - 1. Since it is lowest number in the set of infumums

Comment: It might help to realize that, just as is the case with limits of sequences, neither the lower limit nor the upper limit of a sequence is changed if at most finitely many terms in the sequence are removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Ignore for instance the $(-1)^{n+1}$ term. The rest goes to $1/4$ as $n\to +\infty$. So, all terms of the sequence (if we leave aside the $(-1)^{n+1}$) get arbitrarily close to $1/4$. Now, take into account the $(-1)^{n+1}$. What can you say now about the lowest limit?